# Link to specific ajax tab in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, url, hyperlink, tabs

I have a question that I have not found a answer for yet.

In my Rails 4 application I use ajax tabs. Here is an example for the code setup.

show.html.erb

```
<div id="ajaxtabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><%= link_to 'Members', some_member_path, :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Hosts', some_host_path, :remote => true %></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab-display"></div>
</div>
```

members.js.erb

```
$("#tab-display").html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'members') %>");
```

_members.html.erb

```
 "This is the partial displayed when the members tab is clicked"
```

Everything work beautifully, but there is one feature that I would like to get to work, and that is the ability to link to a specific tab.

For example if I would like to link to the members tab I could type the url maybe like?
sitename.com/groups/#members-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like with your css class names that you're using Bootstrap.  If that is the case then you can call the `tab` function to change to the right tab on page load.

So lets say you have javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var hash = document.location.hash;
      if (hash) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
      }

      $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
      });
    });
</script>
```

This is pretty straightforward -- It takes the arguement from the URL and expects it to match a tab ID. Note that if you've got more than one thing on the page that can use special URLs then JS errors might occur.

Comment: Thanks. It guided me towards a solution checking for the hash, and then fire a click(); on the relevant tab with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

In `members.js.erb` just below `$("#tab-display").html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'members') %>");` you need to add

```
window.location.href= window.location.href + '#members-tab'
```

`#members-tab'` is the value of tab name.

Comment: Well it adds #members-tab to the url when the tab is clicked.
But does not do anything other than that.